# PGAdmin 4 Command line options to open and edit a sql file from command line

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql, pgadmin

What are the command line parameters to launch pgAdmin4 to open and edit a given sql file?

I built a utility to assist in generating sql scripts and edit sql scripts stored in a configuration file.

I have integrated SSMS and Azure Data Studio via code like this:

```
bool edit = buttonContent.StartsWith("Edit");
if (buttonContent.EndsWith("SSMS"))
{
    string exePath = Properties.Settings.Default.SSMS;
    SSMS.EditIn(txtArea, exePath, edit, "-S", conn.DataSource, "-D", conn.Database);
}
```

Where everything past the "edit" parameter are command line arguments passed to the executable via  a System.Diagnostice.Process.

I am able to open PGAdmin via the following ....

```
string exePath = Properties.Settings.Default.Npgsql;
//SQL.EditIn(exePath, edit, "-s", conn.DataSource, "-qc", curr.Setting.ConnectionString);
SQL.EditIn(exePath, edit, "-h", conn.DataSource, "-d",
```

But the script file created inside the "EditIn" method is not being openned by PGADMIN.

The call to pgadmin adds the file name parameter via the "-f" argument.

generating arguments:

```
-h HostName -d DatabaseName -f C:\Users\jholodnak\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7BC5.tmp.sql
```